# User Location leaving artifacts in map kit

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have an interesting problem.  When my map loads, and the user location is being set, an artifact from the animation remains on screen.  Touching and moving the map will remove the artifact.  What might cause this issue?  What might fix this issue?

[image: The larger Blue circle is the artifcat]

Comment: Can you describe the artifact? The picture looks fine to me.

Comment: I wasn't clear...the blue artifact remained stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple fixed the problem in 4.3.